# How to close modalpopupextender placed in a TemplateField without using the BehaviorID property

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need to use a confirmation box like the one [shown here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Confirmation-Confirm-box-with-Yes-No-Buttons-Options-using-AJAX-Modal-Popup-Extender-in-ASPNet.aspx)
The problem is that I also need to add a **close X-button** in the title bar, but the way I usually use to close a modal popup won't work. I think this is because the  BehaviorID must be unique and since it is inside a ItemTemplate , ASP will attempt to create multiple ModalPopupExtender with the same BehaviorID.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
            RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
            runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' OnClick="DeleteRecord"
                            runat="server" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                        <cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbe" runat="server" DisplayModalPopupID="mpe" TargetControlID="lnkDelete">
                        </cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender>
                        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopup" TargetControlID="lnkDelete"
                            OkControlID="btnYes" CancelControlID="btnNo" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                            BehaviorID="mpeClosePopup">
                        </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
                            <div class="header">
                                Confirmation <a href="javascript:;" onclick="ClosePopup('mpeClosePopup');" title="Cerrar">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;X&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="body">
                                Do you want to delete this record?
                            </div>
                            <div class="footer" align="right">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" CssClass="yes" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnNo" runat="server" Text="No" CssClass="no" />
                            </div>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Long story short, do you know how I could close the modal pop-ups if I can not use the BehaviorID for this purpose?? I know this could easily be solved using jQuery , but I'm just not allowed to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the correct `id` of the modal popup extender from the code-behind.

First, remove the `BehaviorId` attribute from your modal popup extender.

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopup" TargetControlID="lnkDelete"
    OkControlID="btnYes" CancelControlID="btnNo" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Second, make your link that closes the popup a server control by giving an `id` and `runat="server"`.

```
<div class="header">
    Confirmation <a id="linkClose" runat="server" href="javascript:;" title="Cerrar">&nbsp;&nbsp;X&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </a>
</div>
```

Third, set an `onclick` for `linkClose` based on the `ClientID` of `mpe` for each row in the grid view by using the `RowDataBound` event of your GridView.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HtmlAnchor linkClose = (HtmlAnchor)e.Row.FindControl("linkClose");
        linkClose.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("ClosePopup('{0}');", e.Row.FindControl("mpe").ClientID));
    }
}
```

Fourth, set the `OnRowDataBound` on your `GridView` control to the same name as the one defined above.

```
OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
```

Lastly, your `ClosePopup` js function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ClosePopup(id) {
        $find(id).hide();
    }
</script>
```

So as an example in the first row, once rendered the link will look something like this with the `onclick` attribute set with the correct id of the modal popup extender.

```
<a id="GridView1_linkClose_0" onclick="ClosePopup('GridView1_mpe_0');" title="Cerrar" href="javascript:;" tabindex="0">  X  </a>
```

Not sure if this is the simplest solution but is what I've done similarly in the past.